# map from observable array to distinct string array

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to retrieve a distinct list of speakers from an observable array of recordings.

I have a json of recording data with a subject and a speaker amongst other data. The user needs to filter this list based on a specific speaker.

```
recordings$: Observable<Recording[]>;

this.recordings$ = this.recordingService.getRecordings();
```

However, to retrieve the list of speakers I would like something like:

```
this.speakers = this.recordings$.map((recording: Recordings) => recording.speaker).disinct();
```

The problem is that the Observable is an Observable of a Recording array. So I cannot simply loop over the recordings and map it to the speaker.

How can I get a distinct list of speakers from my Observable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transform an array of recordings to an array of speakers, containing no duplicate. So you need tow work on arrays, not on observables:

```
this.speakers: Observable<Array<string>> = this.recordings$.map( // 3
  recordings => {
    const speakers = recordings.map(r => r.speaker); // 1
    const distinctSpeakers = [...new Set(speakers)]; // 2
    return distinctSpeakers;
  });
```

1. transform an array of recording into an array of speakers
2. transform an array of speakers into an array of distinct speakers, by storing them in a Set and transforming the Set into an array
3. transform the observable of array of recordings into an observanle of array of distinct speakers.